# JSON Strinfy error in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

This is my json data

```
var jsonData = {
                      'user_id' : userId,
                      'app_id' : '1',
                      'entry_channel' : 'web',
                      'category' : img_category,
                      'title' : postTitle,
                      'post_content' : postContent,
                      'post_type': 'picture',
                      'for_socialevent' : { [eventId] : 'id'},
                };
```

in that `var eventId` is a integer value.

Now this is the response am getting in chrome browser when I stringify the  above json data

```
{"user_id":"20","app_id":"1","entry_channel":"web","category":"socialgroup","title":"yewrtgfauiewrgflasdg","post_content":"sdfgjsdafkas;fsafsafsa","post_type":"picture","for_socialgroup":{}}
```

where as in Firefox am getting a correct response which I need

```
{"user_id":"20","app_id":"1","entry_channel":"web","category":"socialgroup","title":"sada","post_content":"dsadsa","post_type":"picture","for_socialgroup":{"20725":"id"}}
```

anyone could help what mistake I have done or what should be done to get correct result in Chrome.

Comment: you JSON is invalid e.g `'for_socialevent' : { [eventId] : 'id'}, `, ->`'for_socialevent' : { 'eventId': 'id'}`, you should [valid](http://jsonlint.com) your JSON

Comment: @InTry that isn't JSON, it is a javascript object which is being stringified to json. You are confusing the two terms/concepts like many do. It does no good to put a javascript object into jsonlint

Comment: That won't work, it'll use the string key "eventId". You'll need to construct that object manually. That said, it's backwards, id is what it is, not a property of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically create an object key the way you are doing with :

```
 { [eventId] : 'id'},
```

You would need to add that property separately to an already created object

```
var jsonData = {
    'user_id': userId,
        'app_id': '1',
        'entry_channel': 'web',
        'category': img_category,
        'title': postTitle,
        'post_content': postContent,
        'post_type': 'picture',
        'socialevent': {}
};

jsonData.socialevent[eventId] = id;
```

Also as @Dave Newton points out this is probably backwards in your initial code in the first place and should probably be:

```
var jsonData = {
    'user_id': userId,
        'app_id': '1',
        'entry_channel': 'web',
        'category': img_category,
        'title': postTitle,
        'post_content': postContent,
        'post_type': 'picture',
        'socialevent': {'id': eventId}
};
```